Asymptotics of parametric integral using elliptic integrals
I am reading a physics paper, namely "Note on hydrodynamics" by Sir Charles Darwin (I know what you may think, it's not that Darwin) and a relevant quantity (a drift) can be expressed, as a function of a variable $Y$, as
$$ X(Y)= \int_0 ^\pi \frac{a^2 \cos (2 \theta)}{\sqrt{Y^2 + 4 a^2 \sin(\theta)^2 }}d \theta,$$
where $a$ is fixed. Now, I only care about what happens when $Y$ is much greater than $a$ and when $Y$ is much smaller than $a$. In the first case, I can treat the integrand as a function of $Y$ and Taylor expand to obtain the claim in the paper (i.e. that $X(Y)= \pi a^4/2Y^3$). However, for $Y$ small it is way more difficult, at least for me. The author says that for a complete solution one needs to use elliptic integrals. He defines
$$ k= 2a/\sqrt{Y^2 + 4a^2} \text{ and sets } \cos (\theta)= - \operatorname{sn}(\nu).$$
Then he claims that $\nu$ ranges from $-K$ to $K$ and that
$$ X(\nu)= \frac{a}{k} \left[\left( 1- \frac{k^2}{2} \right) \nu - E(\nu)  \right],$$
so
$$ X(Y)= \frac{2a}{k} \left[\left(1- \frac{k^2}{2} \right) K - E  \right]$$
Those $K$ and $E$ should be widely known elliptic functions, as well as the function $\operatorname{sn}$, except that I've never worked with them. He claims that when $Y$ is small "there is a logarithmic infinity", and that $X(Y)= a [ \ln(8a/Y)-2]$. I think this may be easier than it seems, but one might have to use some properties of elliptic functions that I do not know about.

Trying another way, let $Y=2a \sqrt b$ to make (I am using Mathematica notations)
$$I=\frac a 2 \int  \frac{\cos (2 \theta)}{\sqrt{b+\sin ^2(\theta)}}\, d\theta$$
$$I=\frac{a}{2 \sqrt{b}} \left((2 b+1) F\left(t\left|-\frac{1}{b}\right.\right)-2 b
   E\left(t\left|-\frac{1}{b}\right.\right)\right)$$ Using the bounds
$$J=\frac a 2 \int_0^\pi  \frac{\cos (2 \theta)}{\sqrt{b+\sin ^2(\theta)}}\, d\theta=\frac{a}{2 \sqrt{b}} \left(2 (2 b+1) K\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)-4 b
   E\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)\right)$$ Using series expansion
$$ K\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{b} (4 \log (2)-\log (b))+O\left(b^{3/2}\right)$$ and
$$ E\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{b} (-\log (b)+1+4 \log
   (2))+O\left(b^{3/2}\right)$$ Recombining
$$J=a\log \left(\frac{4}{e^2 \sqrt{b}}\right)+ O(b)=a \log \left(\frac{8 a}{e^2 Y}\right)+ O(b)$$ which is the formula.
You could be intrested by this dissertation.

Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! Just some questions: $I$ and $J$ are the same integral, so why the different names? Or you denote with one the indefinite integral and with the other one the definite one? Also, in my question (i.e. in the paper) something is not clear to me. Both $E$ and $K$ are functions, what are the arguments in my last formula? I guess that, since $\nu$ ranges from $-K$ to $K$, $E$ stands for $E(K)$, but what is $K$? I know you're doing it in another way, it's just to try to understand a little better the original argument. Thanks again!

Also, are the formulas you use taken from the source you link? And what do you mean by, for example, $F(t| -1/b)$? You see $F$ as a 2 variables function? I'm just not familiar with the vertical bar insted of the comma

The systematic approach which allows to get the full asymptotics requires the usage of special functions (as was done in the @Claude Leibovici post). However, usually we can extract the leading terms of the asymptotics directly from the initial integral.
Denoting $c=\frac{Y^2}{2a^2}\ll1$ and using $\cos x=1-2\sin^2\frac x2$, our initial integral becomes
$$I(a)= \frac a{2\sqrt2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{c+1-\cos x}}d=\frac a2\int_0^\pi\frac{1-2\sin^2x}{\sqrt{\frac c2+\sin^2x}}dx$$
Denoting for convenience $\frac c2=d$ and making the substitution $x=\arcsin t$
$$=\frac a2\int_{-1}^1\frac{1-2t^2}{\sqrt{d+t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=a\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{d+t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}-2a\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{d+t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\tag{1}$$
The second integral converges at $d=0$, therefore, dropping the terms $\sim o(d)$
$$\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{d+t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\sim\int_0^1\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=1\tag{2}$$
Transforming the first integral in (1)
$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{d+t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\int_0^1\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-1+1\right)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{d+t^2}}=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+1\right)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{d+t^2}}$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{(1+\sqrt{1-t^2})\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{d+t^2}}dt+\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{d+t^2}}\tag{3}$$
Again, the first integral converges at $d=0$; therefore,
$$\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{(1+\sqrt{1-t^2})\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{d+t^2}}dt=\int_0^1\frac{t}{(1+\sqrt{1-t^2})\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt+o(d)$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{1-x})\sqrt{1-x}}+o(d)\overset{1-x=t}{=}\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1+\sqrt t)\sqrt t}+o(d)=\ln2+o(d)\tag{3a}$$
The second integral in (3) has a closed form:
$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{d+t^2}}=-\ln\big(\sqrt{d+t^2}-t\big)\,\bigg|_0^1=\ln\sqrt d-\ln\big(\sqrt{1+d}-1\big)$$
$$=\ln\sqrt d-\ln\frac d{\sqrt{1+d}+1}=-\ln\sqrt d-\ln2+o(d)$$
Putting (3a), 3(b) and (2) into (1) and coming back to the initial notations,
$$I(a)=-2a+a\big(\ln2-\ln\sqrt d+\ln2\big)+o(d)=a\Big(\ln\frac{8a}Y-2\Big)+o\Big(\frac Ya\Big)$$
